# How to get items inside array that is inside Promise.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I am trying to get multiple values from Promise.resolve(), but I am only getting one of two.

What I am trying to do is Insert a row into a database table using ajax. Then, after ajax was successful, I want to update a HTML table (but that doesn't really matter). The problem is, like I said before, I am only getting one of two values back from Promise.resolve(). I used an array as a 'value' with two items inside: the row that was inserted, and Row ID of the inserted row.

I am using express and node.js inside Electron.js. I am new to all of these frameworks.

STEP 1 post request:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "http://localhost:3000/add-row",
        data: {
           username: username
        },
        success: function(response) {
           addRow_to_html_table(response)
```

STEP 2 insert (this part works):

```
return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {

    db_conn.serialize( function () {

      db_conn.run("INSERT INTO table (username) VALUES (?);", [data.username], function (err,result) {

           // passing an array here
           resolve([result, this.lastID])
       
        })

    })
    db_conn.close()

})
```

STEP 3 give back to client:

```
app.post("/add-row", function (req, res) {

  user_info.addRow(req.body).then( function(response) {
    
     // rows is undefined 
     // row_id gives a valid response
     res.json({
        rows: response[0],
        row_id: response[1]
     })

   }).catch(function () {

})
```

})

If I `console.log()` the response, it gives `[ undefined, 45 ] // the inserted row, and row id`

How do i get Promise.resolve() to give me both items that I want?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're getting `[undefined, 45]` it's likely that the problem is step 2. See if `result` is correct there first.

Comment: Speculation: You are closing the connection before the query is resolved so `result` is `undefined`.

Comment: @VLAZ I did that just now. It returned as undefined.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, but why does it still insert into the database table?

Comment: @alexspurlock — There's a reason I said that in a comment with "Speculation" as a prefix and not as an answer.

Comment: It might also help if you told us which library you were using for the database access.